# How to strech UIImageView (iphone dev.)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uiimageview, stretching

I'm studying Objective-c for several months, so I'm beginner.

I have an image `(vertical gradient)` `253px x 80px`. And I want to stretch it to the `screen width`.

How can I make `UIImageView * 1024( or 768) x 80px` with this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 80.0f); 
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect]; 
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient-253x80.png"]]; 
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

Answer (score 3):

A flag used to determine how a view lays out its content when its bounds change.
@property(nonatomic) UIViewContentMode contentMode

> UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

Portrait Mode

```
yourImage.frame = CGRectMake (x start, y start, x width, y width);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look up the documentation on UIImage's method:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

This allows you to make images that can adapt a single small graphic to a variety of sizes and roles.  @Chugaister's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to call:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 1.5, 1);
```

This will stretch the image by a factor of 1.5 on the x axis, but retain y axis dimensions.